# Trying to use wp_set_object_terms while supplying an array for both term id, and texonomies

Tags: terms

I'm trying to use `wp_set_object_terms` ref : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms while passing array for both the terms and taxonomy

for some reason i keep getting : `Warning:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /home1/stodeckc/public_html/clicktranslate/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 231`

this is how i am trying to set it:

```
parents[] = array(
    'item_id' => 15,
    'app_name' => 'justanotherone'
);

foreach($parents as $parent){
    $cat_ids[$parent['item_id']] = (int)$parent['item_id'];
    $taxonomies[$parent['item_id']] = $parent['app_name'];
}
wp_set_object_terms( 42, $cat_ids,$taxonomies);
```

am i missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting the array index?

Comment: The warning message shows the `$taxonomies` you pass to `wp_set_object_terms` might be empty or wrong type. Could you dump the `$cat_ids` and `$taxonomies` to see what are the values?

Answer (score 1):

what i ended up doing:

```
foreach($this->parents as $parent){
            $taxonomies[] = $parent['app_name'];
        }
        wp_delete_object_term_relationships( (int)$parent['item_id'], array_unique( $taxonomies ) );

        foreach($this->parents as $parent){
            $cat_id = (int)$parent['item_id'];
            $taxonomy = $parent['app_name'];
            wp_set_object_terms( (int)$parent['item_id'], $cat_id,$taxonomy, true);
        }
```

This solution is a little longer but it worked and i couldn't spend more time searching the problem.

Thanks